# How can I increase laptop lcd luminosity steps?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, laptop, monitor, screen

I was wondering if there's a way to tweak the steps that the luminosity of my lcd do when adjusting it from keyboard.

It seems that they are just +/-30% of total, and that's pretty annoying, because sometimes it would be useful to have more control on it.
As an example now: 0 is too low, but 30% is too high. I can reach 10% by letting it 100% and then down 30 by 30 until 10, but it's still too low.

I'd like to have a more fine control on it, like the 18 steps of the sound.

I'm on an Acer Extensa 5620, here's my lshw:

```
$ sudo lshw -short -sanitize
H/W path               Device      Class       Description
==========================================================
                                   system      Notebook
/0                                 bus         Columbia
/0/0                               memory      105KiB BIOS
/0/4                               processor   Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5550  @ 1.83GHz
/0/4/5                             memory      64KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                             memory      2MiB L2 cache
/0/4/1.1                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/4/1.2                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/10                              memory      3GiB System Memory
/0/10/0                            memory      1GiB SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 667 MHz (1,5 ns)
/0/10/1                            memory      2GiB SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 667 MHz (1,5 ns)
/0/1                               processor   
/0/1/1.1                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/1/1.2                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/100                             bridge      Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub
/0/100/2                           display     Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
/0/100/2.1                         display     Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
/0/100/1a                          bus         82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
/0/100/1a.1                        bus         82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
/0/100/1a.7                        bus         82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
/0/100/1b                          multimedia  82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                          bridge      82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1
/0/100/1c/0            eth0        network     NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
/0/100/1c.1                        bridge      82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2
/0/100/1c.1/0          wlan0       network     PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
/0/100/1c.2                        bridge      82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3
/0/100/1d                          bus         82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
/0/100/1d.1                        bus         82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
/0/100/1d.2                        bus         82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
/0/100/1d.7                        bus         82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
/0/100/1e                          bridge      82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
/0/100/1e/6                        bridge      PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
/0/100/1e/6.1                      bus         PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller
/0/100/1e/6.2                      storage     5-in-1 Multimedia Card Reader (SD/MMC/MS/MS PRO/xD)
/0/100/1e/6.3                      generic     PCIxx12 SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller
/0/100/1f                          bridge      82801HEM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller
/0/100/1f.1            scsi0       storage     82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller
/0/100/1f.1/0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk        DVDRAM GSA-T40N
/0/100/1f.2            scsi2       storage     82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA IDE Controller
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk        250GB Hitachi HTS54252
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/1    /dev/sda1   volume      26GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/2    /dev/sda2   volume      17GiB Extended partition
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/2/5  /dev/sda5   volume      3200MiB Linux swap / Solaris partition
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/2/6  /dev/sda6   volume      14GiB Linux filesystem partition
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/3    /dev/sda3   volume      189GiB EXT3 volume
/0/100/1f.3                        bus         82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller
/0/2                   scsi12      storage     
/0/2/0.0.0             /dev/sdb    disk        SCSI Disk
```

Any tip?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably ...

### Directly

```
echo '100' > /sys/class/backlight/psb-bl/brightness
echo `'50' > /sys/class/backlight/psb-bl/brightness
```

You simply have to adjust the path, `/sys/class/backlight/your_device/brightness`

### xbacklight

Alternately you can try installing xbacklight

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight

xbacklight -inc 10
xbacklight -dec 10
xbacklight -set 60
```

See [man xbacklight](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xbacklight.1.html)

Comment: I've got 2 devices listed in /sys/class/backlight/: acpi_video0 and intel_backlight. The first is the one with changing luminosity when using keyboard, while the other one's is always 0. The range is 0-9, moving 4 by 4 from keyboard. Using the first codes (with sudo) says me a no No permission error. I'll try xbacklight now.

Comment: Ok, xbacklight is working, but just with a 20% increment, with some strange steps too. Starting from 0 and using several times `xbacklight -inc 20 &&  xbacklight -get` I get 11.111111, 22.222222, 33.333333, 44.444444, 55.555556, 66.666667, 77.777778, 88.888889, 100.000000. Anyway, many thanks :) I'll try add it to some keyboard combinations.

Comment: You might be looking at a limitation of your hardware, I am not sure. Try `sudo echo '40' > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0`

Comment: `sudo echo '40' > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0`
`bash: /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0: È una directory` (It is a directory) and `sudo echo '40' > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` `bash: /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness: Permesso negato` (No Permission)

Comment: @dadexix86, I have the same and acpi_video0 seems like a generalized version of intel_backlight, as echo'ng 0 to intel_backlight/brightness totally blacks the screen, whereas doing so to acpi_video0/brightness only dims to a certain level.